# Организация поля списка

Tags: база-данных, php, html, javascript, mysql

Ка организовать поле списка? Аналог ListBox в дельфи. Чтоб он наполнялся из БД. Строки можно было удалить/добавить и они отредактированные возвращались в БД? А то перерыл пол интернета и ничего не нашел.

Comment: Массивы используйте.

Answer (score 1):

Вас интересуют редактируемые таблицы, я так полагаю ) Организовать - самостоятельно, прописывая клиент-сервер + валидации не забудьте.
Ну и для клиента есть симпатишные плагины, если jQuery, то, например, [вот](http://www.trirand.net/demophp.aspx) (честно говоря, сама пока не использовала, но возможностей очевидно у него много). Или посмотрите javascript библиотеку ExtJS - в ней множество разнообразных компонент.

Comment: То что по ссылке - платная

Comment: ой :) спасибо, что заметили, а то я к ней приглядывалась

Comment: Хотя по сути потрясающая вещь. Может кто знает что нибудь подоное, но бесплатное

Comment: Если не лень разбираться - то, еще раз говорю, есть ExtJS - вот тут демки http://www.sencha.com/products/extjs/examples/#sample-2 
Проблема с ExtJS в том, что это уже отдельный фреймворк, который сложнее и обширнее jQuery, а, следовательно, требует больше трудозатрат

Comment: Оно тоже платное.

Comment: нет, она по 2м лицензиям - коммерческая и GPL v3.